# Hibernate error - QuerySyntaxException: admins is not mapped [SELECT o FROM admins o WHERE o.username = :username]

Tags: hibernate

I've been playing around with a very simple JPA example and am trying to tweak it to an existing database. But I can't get past this error. (Below.) It just has to be some simple thing I am not seeing.
I'm trying to get my admin from "Admins" table and I this is the error (you find it further down)

This is the code I wrote to get admins:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AdminsService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public AdminsService() {}

    public Long getSize() {
        String query = "SELECT count(o) FROM Log o";
        return (Long)em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    }

    public void create(Admins o) {
        em.persist(o);
    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        Admins o = find(id);
        if (o.getId() != 0) em.remove(o);
    }

    public Admins find(Long id) {
        return em.find(Admins.class, id);
    }

    public Admins findByUsername(String username) {
        String query="SELECT o FROM Admins o WHERE o.username = :username";
        Admins u = null;
        try {
            return (Admins)em.createQuery(query).setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e1) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return u;
    }

    public List<Admins> getAll() {
        TypedQuery<Admins> query = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Admins o", Admins.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

this is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ejb">
        <jta-data-source>java:/Sportunion1</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this my Admins-Class:

```
@Entity
public class Admins {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 24)
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

Any idea why I get this error?

**UPDATE**

I have done following the comments this structure and this files at my project:

[image: project structure]

and i still get this error:

```
    11:04:41,467 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Admins is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Admins o WHERE o.username = :username]

11:04:41,468 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)

11:04:41,468 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)

11:04:41,468 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)

11:04:41,469 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)

11:04:41,469 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:445)

11:04:41,469 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.sportunion.project.AdminsService.findByUsername(AdminsService.java:44)

11:04:41,480 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.sportunion.project.AdminsService$$$view13.findByUsername(Unknown Source)

11:04:41,480 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.sportunion.LoginView$1.buttonClick(LoginView.java:58)

11:04:41,489 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Admins is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Admins o WHERE o.username = :username]

11:04:41,492 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Admins is not mapped

11:04:41,493 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   ... 128 more

11:04:41,500 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-13) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component LogService for method public void org.sportunion.project.LogService.add(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: org.sportunion.project.domain.Log
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at org.sportunion.project.LogService$$$view16.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.sportunion.LoginView$1.buttonClick(LoginView.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: org.sportunion.project.domain.Log
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1184)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580)
    at org.sportunion.project.LogService.create(LogService.java:40)
    at org.sportunion.project.LogService.add(LogService.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 89 more

11:04:41,508 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-13) : javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: org.sportunion.project.domain.Log
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at org.sportunion.project.LogService$$$view16.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.sportunion.LoginView$1.buttonClick(LoginView.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: org.sportunion.project.domain.Log
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1184)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580)
    at org.sportunion.project.LogService.create(LogService.java:40)
    at org.sportunion.project.LogService.add(LogService.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 89 more
```

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml-File:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sportunion</property>
        <property name="connection.username">radius</property>
        <property name="connection.password">radpass</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="org/sportunion/project/domain/Admins.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/sportunion/project/domain/Log.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/sportunion/project/domain/Nas.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/sportunion/project/domain/Users.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and this my Admins.hbm.xml-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.sportunion.project.domain">
<class name="Admins" table="admins">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username"/>
        <property name="password"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be either you don't have Admins  listed in your hibernat.cfg.xml or where ever you config your mapped classes.

Or make sure you  are using org.hibernate....Entity import.

Comment: i don't have any hibernat.cfg.xml file, because without maven it works fine for me this way... now I want to get my application on maven and this is my error... how has a hibernat.cfg.xml to look like? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Where have u mentioned that hibernate needs to scan for your entities?

Comment: http://www.javabeat.net/hibernate-4-configuration-example/ look at this tutorial how they have a hibernate.cfg and have mentioned employee.cfg in it

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I will update my question.

Comment: Even after the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, even after the tutorial I have also cleaned und updated both projects and then installed it. :-/

Comment: Do you have configs now?

Comment: Meaning hibernate.xml and admin.xml

Comment: Above you can see an updated picture of my project structure. And yes i have added those files :-/

Comment: Can u post the import that you have in admins.java

Comment: I will post it in an hour when I am back at home

Comment: this are my imports: `import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size; `

Comment: Your imports look fine

Comment: I am sorry if it taking this long doing my best to resolve

Comment: Please post your xml files

Comment: I have post it above in my question at the end. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: try changing your <class name="Admins" table="admins"> to <class name="Admins" table="Admins">

Comment: Try remaining entity from your admins class

Comment: thanks, I have found my mistake in the ohter persistence.xml :) now I have another error but for this I will make a new question :)